# Show the biggest number entered using while loop in C?

Tags: c

I am creating a small program which uses a while loop to ask user to enter number(s) bigger than 0. When the program runs only the loop works, but I don't see the biggest number. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

        int num1;
        int biggestValue = 0;

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        while (num1 != 0) {

                printf("Enter a number (0 to exit): ");
                scanf("%d", &num1);

                biggestValue = num1;

                if (biggestValue > num1) {

                        printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: You have `biggestValue = num1` followed by `if (biggestValue > num1)`. Since you just assigned `num1` to `biggestValue`, then they'll be equal and the `if` condition will never be true.

Comment: *"This question was caused by a a simple typographical error."*

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question "How do you debug C code?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set `biggestValue` until it is shown to be greater.

Change compare order [@Zaman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288906/show-the-biggest-number-entered-using-while-loop-in-c/33289229#comment54378526_33289229)

```
            // biggestValue = num1;
            if (num1 > biggestValue) {
              biggestValue = num1;  // move here
              printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
            }
```

A sample complete solution:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int biggestValue = INT_MIN;
  const char *prompt = "Enter a number: ";
  for (;;) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    int num1;
    if (scanf("%d", &num1) != 1) break;
    if (num1 > biggestValue) {
      biggestValue = num1;
    }
    prompt = "Enter a number (or 'q' to exit): ";
  }
  printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to accomplish, but your code is a bit to advance because I am a beginner, but still thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int num1;
    int biggestValue = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    while (num1 != 0)
    {

        if (biggestValue < num1)
        {
            biggestValue = num1;
        }
        printf("Enter a number (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
    }
    printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
}
```

Explanation:

1. First you need to check the entered number `num1` is greater than `biggestValue` or not.
2. If `num1` is greater than `biggestValue` then  `biggestValue=num1`.
3. Else `biggestValue` remain unchanged.
4. Outside loop print the `biggestValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting `biggestValue = num1;` and then immediately checking if `biggestValue > num1`, `biggestValue` can never be bigger than `num1`. They'll always be equal.

I think what you want is:

```
if (biggestValue < num1) {
    biggestValue = num1;
}
```

And then outside of the while loop you'd place:

```
printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
```

Comment: condition should be `if(biggestValue<num1){`

Answer (score 0):

The printing should be just after the while loop,and don't write `biggestValue = num1;` before the comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;

    int biggestValue = 0;

    while (num1 != 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a number (0 to exit): ");

        scanf("%d", &num1);

        if (biggestValue < num1)
        {
            biggestValue = num1;
        }
    }
    printf("Biggest value is: %d \n", biggestValue);
}
```